# Unable to record in VUGEN 12.01 with IE11.0

Tags: internet-explorer-11, recording, vugen

I'm using LR Vugen 12.01 tool to record an application in HTTP/HTML protocol. We have IE upgraded to 11.0 version now, when I try to record using 11.0 I'm getting the message saying 'webpage can't be displayed'.

Any specific settings we need to do for recording using 12.01 with IE11? Earlier I was able to record with IE 8 version without any issues.

Please let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LoadRunner local proxy recording if flow is working manually in ie11.